# extra <li> being created with jquery .append()

Tags: jquery, json

I am appending a json response to an html element. The code is very simple

HTML

```
<div>
  <ul id='grid'></ul>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
data = ["Paintings",{ "age":0}]

$(function() {
   $.each(data, function(i,index) {         
     $('div').find('ul').append('<li>'+index.age+'</li>');
  });
});
```

The output looks like this

undefined

0

Where is the undefined coming from??

I tried using this to remove the undefined

```
$('#grid').children(':first-child').remove('li');
```

but it removes the "0" and the undefined.

http://jsfiddle.net/ccUKH/

Comment: What do you get if you do a `console.log()` for `data`, `i`, and/or `index`?

Comment: You have an array with two elements and you loop through it. Why do you expect the first element would be ignored?

Comment: Well you do have 2 items in the array that `each` will go through... the first one doesn't have `age` so it'll be undefined... the second one will be 0 because `"age":0` works like it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is an array, the first element of array is a string `Paintings`. Second element of array is an object with property `age`.

The `each` loops over both elements in array and since string has no property `age` it creates an LI with text `undefined`  .

You could change the data structure or look for `object` or `string` in array and react accordingly...not sure what you want to do. Not clear what you are doing with `Paintings`

Answer (score 1):

Your data is an array containing two elements, a string `'Paintings'` and an object `{age:0}`.

When your code iterates over 'data', `data.0.age` evaluates as 'Undefined' (because it is a string and cannot have children), and `data.1.age` evaluates as '0'.

There's also no need to find the `<ul>` in the `<div>` because you have given the `<ul>` and id of "grid" (unless you want to append this data to every `<div>` containing a `<ul>`).

Try restructuring the data, and directly targeting your `<ul>` like this:

```
data = {"Paintings" : [{"age":0}, {"age":5}]};

$.each(data.Paintings, function(i,index) {
  $('#grid').append('<li>'+index.age+'</li>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ccUKH/2/

Answer (score 1):

The `undefined` is from `"Pages".age`.  Try this:

```
$.each(data, function(i,index) {
    if (index.hasOwnProperty('age')) {         
        $('div').find('ul').append('<li>'+index.age+'</li>');
    }
});
```